# how wordpress generates permalinks as /%category%/%post%/

Tags: categories, permalinks

I am not here to discuss the efficiency of using categories as the base for permalinks.

I would like to know in **what file and what line is the code to how Wordpress picks out a category for the permalink if the post is in multiple categories**. I asked this on IRC a while ago and I can't find the code anymore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_permalink` in `/wp-includes/link-template.php`, line 80